# How can I change the option of Brackets Beautify?

Tags: adobe-brackets, js-beautify

I want to change the option of Brackets Beautify.

```
"newline_between_rules": true
```

to

```
"newline_between_rules": false
```

How can I change this?

Comment: According to the [Brackets repository](https://github.com/brackets-beautify/brackets-beautify), you can edit settings with a `.jsbeautifyrc` file.

Comment: However, I cannot find the file in `Brackets>extensions>user>brackets-beautify`.

Comment: Well you just create it and start a simple json object in it with all the possible attributes you want to change. Here they are: https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md